# SpamAssassin RDNS_DYNAMIC and HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR

Tags: spamassassin

I'm using SendGrid to deliver emails and the recent test I conducted from my server, using their API, ended up having SpamAssassin flagging my email. Here is the result:

```
pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                           See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block for more information.
                         [URIs: sendgrid.net]
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
0.0 T_SPF_HELO_TEMPERROR   SPF: test of HELO record failed (temperror)
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                         [score: 0.0000]
0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
2.0 HTTPS_HTTP_MISMATCH    BODY: No description available.
1.1 KAM_REALLYHUGEIMGSRC   RAW: Spam with image tags with ridiculously huge
                          http urls
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                         domain
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
2.6 RDNS_DYNAMIC           Delivered to internal network by host with
                         dynamic-looking rDNS
2.0 HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR    Relay HELO'd using suspicious hostname (IP addr 1)
X-Spam-Flag: YES
```

The webhosting company I'm using just came back to me saying that they fixed the problem by disabling SpamAssassin from my server. I might need a better solution.

So the main question I have is: who should I contact to get the following lines fixed? My webhost, Sendgrid or someone else?

```
2.6 RDNS_DYNAMIC Delivered to internal network by host with dynamic-looking rDNS
2.0 HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR    Relay HELO'd using suspicious hostname (IP addr 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR** indicates that the sending server connected to the receiving server and announced itself with an *IP address* rather than a *Fully Qualified Domain Name* (FQDN), and **RDNS_DYNAMIC** indicates that the Reverse DNS check on that IP address resolves to something that resembles the FQDN of a dynamically issued IP address.

To rectify this you would need to get the rDNS of your sending IP to resolve to a plausible FQDN, and in turn use that FQDN in the HELO / EHLO handshake. Both of these relate to the MX phase of your message exchange, and would be caused by the sending server, but maybe your sender doesn't want to announce themselves *overtly* to avoid other more direct SPAM rules from being applied to their perceived sender reputation ?

I would have expected SendGrid to send on your behalf using your domain name during the *HELO* handshake, and consequently require their sending IP ranges to be included in  any SPF records for your domain.

Historically it used to be misconfigured *Exchange Servers* that announced the IP address during the *HELO* handshake, because unwitting admins entered an IP address in the FQDN field of their Send Connectors.

Comment: I went ahead and added a rDNS entry. That fixed the issue. Thanks Gavin!